# Drop rows where timestamps are older than subsequent row

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, datetime

I'm trying to drop rows where timestamps are older or later than subsequent rows. I'm not sure if I'm overthinking this but my current attempt below.

**Note: I don't want to sort timestamps so it's ordered. I want to remove or drop them altogether.**

The df below is just an example. I need this code for varying input datasets where the number of *unordered* timestamps is different.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : ['1/1/1900 8:00:00','1/1/1900 9:49:00','1/1/1900 10:00:00','1/1/1900 12:33:00','1/1/1900 12:35:00','1/1/1900 12:24:00','1/1/1900 13:42:00','1/1/1900 13:45:00','1/1/1900 14:21:00','1/1/1900 14:36:00'],                 
    'Number' : [1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,3,4],                      
    })

df['Time'] = df['Time'].astype('datetime64')

df['diff'] = df['Time'] - df['Time'].shift(-1)

df['diff'] = df['diff'].dt.total_seconds()

df['diff'].fillna(0, inplace=True) 

df['diff'] = df['diff'].astype(int)

df = df[df['diff'] < 1]
```

Out:

```
                 Time  Number  diff
0 1900-01-01 08:00:00       1 -6540
1 1900-01-01 09:49:00       2  -660
2 1900-01-01 10:00:00       2 -9180
3 1900-01-01 12:33:00       2  -120 *Rows below are 12:24:00
5 1900-01-01 12:24:00       1 -4680
6 1900-01-01 13:42:00       2  -180
7 1900-01-01 13:45:00       2 -2160
8 1900-01-01 14:21:00       3  -900
9 1900-01-01 14:36:00       4     0
```

Intended df:

```
                Time  Number  diff
0 1900-01-01 08:00:00       1 -6540
1 1900-01-01 09:49:00       2  -660
2 1900-01-01 10:00:00       2 -9180
5 1900-01-01 12:24:00       1 -4680
6 1900-01-01 13:42:00       2  -180
7 1900-01-01 13:45:00       2 -2160
8 1900-01-01 14:21:00       3  -900
9 1900-01-01 14:36:00       4     0
```

It picked up Index 4 but not Index 3. I don't know if I should create a script that interates though until there are no positive numbers or there's an easier way.

Comment: why is `5 1900-01-01 12:24:00       1 -4680` in the expected output, can you explain in short? Thanks

Comment: It is before the subsequent rows? So it's in order.

Comment: @anky_91 he's saying you should remove rows with 'older' timestamp not remove based on 'newer' 5 1900-01-01 12:24:00 1 -4680 is not older than any subsequent rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```py
def myfunc(t,l):
    try:
        return not (t > min(l))
    except:
        return True

df[df.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x.Time,df.Time.iloc[x.name+1:len(df)].to_list()),axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
s=df.Time.diff().dt.total_seconds()
df[(~s.lt(0)|s.isnull())]
                 Time  Number              diff
0 1900-01-01 08:00:00       1 -1 days +22:11:00
1 1900-01-01 09:49:00       2 -1 days +23:49:00
2 1900-01-01 10:00:00       2 -1 days +21:27:00
3 1900-01-01 12:33:00       2 -1 days +23:58:00
4 1900-01-01 12:35:00       1          00:11:00
6 1900-01-01 13:42:00       2 -1 days +23:57:00
7 1900-01-01 13:45:00       2 -1 days +23:24:00
8 1900-01-01 14:21:00       3 -1 days +23:45:00
9 1900-01-01 14:36:00       4               NaT
```

Comment: Thanks for making it more efficient but I still encounter the same issue?